# Generic Type as generic type parameter

Tags: java, generics

I want to know if I can improve my class, by avoiding the second V in the declaration of my class. Somehow it looks awful.

```
public abstract class TreeElementAction<T extends TreeNode<V>, V> {

    protected abstract boolean actFor(@Nullable T element);

    public void forEachElementInTree(@Nonnull T rootNode) {
        requireNonNull(rootNode);
        actFor(rootNode);

        Collection<T> children = (Collection<T>) rootNode.getChildren();
        for (T treeNode : children) {
            forEachElementInTree(treeNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to be using it, so you can drop it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you require `V` in any of the concrete implementations of this class, you can just drop the type variable, as @PeterLawrey has suggested, and replace it with an unbounded wildcard in `TreeNode<V>`:

```
public abstract class TreeElementAction<T extends TreeNode<?>> {
```